# Overriden implementations of equals() and compareTo() never got called

Tags: java, overriding, comparable

I need to be able to sort User objects based on first name and last name. To do so I overrided the `compareTo()` method as part of the `Comparable` interface. However, when I use `Collections.sort(users)`, where `users` is an ArrayList of `User` objects, my overrided implementation of `compareTo()` never gets called. Similarly, I overrided `equals()` to check for equality of various fields in `User`; name, address, email address, etc. This overrided implementation is never called either for `users.remove(thisUser)`. Here is my code for the overriden methods:

```
public class User implements Comparable<User> {
    [other methods and fields go here]

    @Override
    public int compareTo(User aUser) {
        System.out.println("Comparing.....");
        return (this.lastName.compareTo(aUser.getLastName()) < 0 ? -1 : 
                this.lastName.compareTo(aUser.getLastName()) > 0 ? 1 :
                this.firstName.compareTo(aUser.getFirstName()) < 0 ? -1 :
                this.firstName.compareTo(aUser.getFirstName()) > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this.firstName == ((User) o).getFirstName() &&
           this.lastName == ((User) o).getLastName() &&
           this.email == ((User) o).getEmail() &&
           this.address == ((User) o).getAddress() &&
           this.gender == ((User) o).getGender()) {
               return true;
        }
        return false;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return super.hashCode();
   }
```

I am adding entries by simply calling: `users.add(newUser)`, which works fine. 
For example, I'll add "John Doe", "Bert S", "Al S", and "Steven X", and they remain in the order I added them in.

Calling the methods:
When I write the entries back to a file, I first sort them:
     `Collections.sort(users);`

When I remove a user: 
     `users.remove(thisUser);`

Both adding, deleting, and sorting are just each one line.

Why won't either of these methods get called by `users.remove()` or `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: Because you've not overridden `hashCode`....? Actually, no. That'd be why `equals` isn't called for a `HashSet`. How are you sure that they're *not* called? (But you *should* override `hashCode` anyway).

Comment: @AndyTurner That might explain failure to call `equals`. What about `compareTo`?

Comment: Please post working code that shows what you are experiencing. The problem may well be in the way you are putting things in the list, etc.

Comment: Are you sure that there are actually objects in your `ArrayList users`? If yes, please add a minimal main and your jdk Version please.

Comment: I copy-pasted this snippet to my IDE, added all the members you're referencing as strings and let my IDA auto-generate a constructor and getters for all of them. When sorting an array with two such `User` objects, your `compareTo` is called just fine. Can you give a concrete example that makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Also, are you aware that you shouldn't compare strings using `==`? Unless you are really trying to compare them by identity, I mean.

Comment: 1) You should override hashcode not just by calling `super.hashcode()` but also changing its effect.
2) Please, specify which Collection do you use?

Comment: @AndyTurner I added a print statement in the methods to check, and nothing is ever printed. When I sort, nothing actually gets sorted.

Comment: @SVN600 please add the code that you use to try to get these methods to be called. There is something not quite right, but we can't say what if you don't show us.

Comment: One simple explanation of all the symptoms would be if `sort` and `remove` were being called on an empty `ArrayList`, not the one the OP intended to call them on.

Answer (score 2):

equals will call only if hashCode differs

Please check this code, it's calling compareTo,

```
 User  user1 = new User();
        user1.setFirstName("testFirst");
        user1.setLastName("testLast");
        User  user2 = new User();
        user2.setFirstName("testFirst1");
        user2.setLastName("testLast1");
        List<User> list = Arrays.asList(user1, user2);
        Collections.sort(list);
```

Output: 
   Comparing.....

```
public class User implements Comparable<User> {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println("hashCode.....");
        int result = lastName.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + firstName.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(User aUser) {
        System.out.println("Comparing.....");
        return (this.lastName.compareTo(aUser.getLastName()) < 0 ? -1 :
                this.lastName.compareTo(aUser.getLastName()) > 0 ? 1 :
                        this.firstName.compareTo(aUser.getFirstName()) < 0 ? -1 :
                                this.firstName.compareTo(aUser.getFirstName()) > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        System.out.println("equals.....");
        if (this.firstName == ((User) o).getFirstName() &&
                this.lastName == ((User) o).getLastName()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```